# Rotated bitmap is losing quality on every rotate

Tags: android, image, kotlin, rotation

I am using the following function to rotate my bitmap. I noticed that if I rotate this bitmap a few times, it loses quality at every rotate upto a point that it becomes just a image with solid colour. I tried with PNG instead of JPEG but the size goes up drastically. Is there any solution to rotate the image without losing quality and increasing size?

```
 fun rotatedImage(path:String):Bitmap{
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path)
        val mat = Matrix()
        if (rotateDegree==270f) rotateDegree = 0f
        mat.postRotate(rotateDegree+90)
        val bMapRotate=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true)
        deleteImageFile(path)
        val fileStream = FileOutputStream(path)
        // Tried with PNG as well = Size increases
        bMapRotate.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileStream)
        return bMapRotate
    }
```

Comment: JPEG is lossy, so by definition you'll lose data every time you re-encode a JPEG image.

Comment: "I noticed that if I rotate this bitmap a few times" -- then just rotate it once or not at all. For example, if you are trying to display a rotated image, rotate the `ImageView`, not the image. Only rotate the actual bitmap (and save it to the file) when you have your final rotation angle, if ever.